# Datatables plugin jquery: al Exportar como PDF oculta los Inputs parámetros exportación

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

hola tengo un problema: Estoy usando datatables plugin for jquery; y sucede que al intentar exportar a PDF usando el boton de las herramientas simplemente me genera el archivo pero oculta los Inputs tengan o no tengan valor las columnas estas se muestran vacías; existe alguna manera de evitarlo:

**Configuración(Código):**

```
$('.DataTableHelper1').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"html5buttons"B>rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
        "language": {
            "decimal":      ".",
            "emptyTable":       "No hay datos disponibles en la tabla",
            "info":         "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Registros",
            "infoEmpty":        "Mostrando 0 a 0 de 0 Registros",
            "infoFiltered":     "(Filtrado a Partir de _MAX_ Registros)",
            "infoPostFix":      "",
            "thousands":        ",",
            "lengthMenu":       "_MENU_",
            "loadingRecords":   "Cargando...",
            "processing":       "Procesando...",
            "search":       "Buscar:",
            "zeroRecords":      "No Encontrado - lo siento",
            "paginate": {
                "first":        "Inicio",
                "last":         "Ultimo",
                "next":         "Siguiente",
                "previous":     "Anterior"
            },
            "aria": {
                "sortAscending":  ": activar para ordenar la columna ascendente",
                "sortDescending": ": activar para ordenar la columna descendente"
            }
        },
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "lengthMenu": [[-1], ["All"]],
        "ordering": false,
        "scrollY": "300px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Herramientas',
            buttons: [
                {extend: 'copy', text: 'Copiar',exportOptions: {columns: ':visible'},},
                {extend: 'excel', title: 'ArchivoExcel', text: 'Excel',exportOptions: {columns: ':visible'},},
                {extend: 'pdfHtml5', title: 'ArchivoPDF', text: 'PDF',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: true,
                    },
                },
                {extend: 'print', text: 'Imprimir',
                    customize: function (win){
                        $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                        $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                        $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                    },
                    exportOptions: {columns: ':visible'},
                },
            ]},
            {extend: 'colvis', text: 'Adm',},
            {
                text: 'Ayuda',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    $.jAlert({
                        'title': 'Ayuda de Herramientas',
                        'content': msgtext,
                        'theme': 'blue',
                        'size': 'lg',
                        'showAnimation': 'fadeInUp',
                        'hideAnimation': 'fadeOutDown'
                    });
                }
            },
        ]
    });
```

[Link referencia](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43735/datatable-export-pdf-with-inputs-not-show-input-with-data)

**Actualización:**

Encontré parte de un código que permite determinar el contenido de la celda pero solo lo hace a la columna 5 me gustaría que esto lo hiciera en todas las columnas, solo hace una limpieza del texto, pero en mi caso requiero que obtenga el valor del input del formulario en cualquier de sus controles: Checkbox, textarea, checkbox, select option:

```
exportOptions: {
    format: {
        body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
            // convierte el texto en un valor numerico
            return column === 5 ?
                data.replace( /[$,]/g, '' ) :
                data;
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: A ver si  entiendo. Tienes <input type="text" /> en cada `td` y necesitas el valor que esta en ellos?

Comment: Trato de entender, tienes input dentro de la tabla y estos se ocultan o es que se ocultan inputs de afuera de la tabla? O te refieres a que en el PDF generado se ocultan esos datos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajusta la seccion `format` de esta parte de tu código:

```
exportOptions: {
    columns: ':visible',
    stripHtml: true,
    format: {
        body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
            var retorno="",tag,respuesta="",reponer=[];                             
            tag = $(node).find('input:hidden');
            if(tag.length>0){for(i=0;i<tag.length;i++){reponer.push(tag[i]);$(tag[i]).remove();}}
            tag = $(node).find('input:radio');
            if(tag.length>0){retorno=retorno + ($(node).find(':checked').length>0?$(node).find(':checked').val():" ");}
            tag = $(node).find('input:checkbox');
            if(tag.length==1){retorno=retorno + ($(node).find(':checked').length>0?"Si":"No");
            }else if(tag.length>1){retorno=retorno + ($(node).find(':checked').length>0?$(node).find(':checked').val():" ");}
            tag = $(node).find('input,select,textarea').not(':radio,:checkbox,:hidden');
            if(tag.length>0){retorno=retorno + ($(tag).map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(','));}

            respuesta=(retorno!="")?retorno:$.trim($(node).text());
            for(i=0;i<reponer.length;i++){$(node).append(reponer[i]);}

            return respuesta;
        }
    },
},
```

Tiene soporte para todos los elementos de `form`.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65211/discussion-on-answer-by-juliocpiro-datatables-plugin-jquery-al-exportar-como-pd).

Answer (score 1):

El parametro `node` represente el elemento `td` actual que esta siendo formateado por lo que para obtener el valor del input en ese `td`, solo tienes que buscar el `input` y obtener su valor:

```
exportOptions: {
    format: {
        body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
              // convierte el texto en un valor numerico
              return $(node).find(".control-input").val();
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: déjame revisar :) pero la idea es que puede ser cualquier tipo de input: checkbox, input, select box, textarea, cualquier de estos campos para formulario.

Comment: Bueno como no publicaste que tipos de controles utilizas, tendras que adaptar la solucion a la forma en como te funcione.

Comment: "Busco una respuesta exacta para resolver este problema. 0 Adaptaciones." lo dice en la propuesta de la recompensa.

Comment: A los controles asignales una clase para poder identificarlos y luego obten el valor del control. Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: no funciona para todos...

Comment: El que no funciona? Puedes ser mas especifico?

Comment: Jamas funcionara para todos, el textArea no es un input. Tal vez funcione con inputs pero con el textArea no lo hará porque se comporta diferente

Comment: yo se que no funcionaria con todos los elementos(Controles) de un form, la pregunta es como se haría para que lo haga.

Comment: Pero el que no funciona para todos los controles? Obtener el valor con la funcion `val()`? [Hasta donde tengo conocimiento si](http://jsbin.com/jeriheloyi/edit?html,js,console,output)